# Adding TabHost control into Linearlayout/Adding layout under the tabhost tabs

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost, android-tabs, tabwidget

I have created an application with four tabs loaded with specific webviews. I planned to add advertisement below the tabs. In my code I have set the content view as the ViewGroup created as TabHost. If I am add this Viewgroup to linearlayout the application have been crashed due to the TabHost.add(TabSpec) gets NullPointer exception. Here is the code.

```
 public View addTabBarView(Context context)
{        
     m_vForm = _createTABForm(context);
     return m_vForm;
}     
private ViewGroup _createTABForm(Context context) {

    sTabHost = new TabHost(context,null);
    sTabHost.setLayoutParams(
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));        
    HorizontalScrollView sScrollView = new HorizontalScrollView(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams sScrollViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    sScrollView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    sScrollView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    sScrollView.setScrollBarStyle(TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN);
    sScrollView.setFillViewport(true);

    TabWidget tabWidget = new TabWidget(context); 
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams sTabWidgetParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
    tabWidget.setId(android.R.id.tabs);
    sScrollView.addView(tabWidget, sTabWidgetParams);          
    sTabHost.addView(sScrollView, sScrollViewParams);         
    FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(context);
    frameLayout.setId(android.R.id.tabcontent);
    final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int paddingtop = (int) (64 * scale + 0.5f);
    frameLayout.setPadding(0, paddingtop, 0, 0);
    sTabHost.addView(frameLayout, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
              LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));         

    sTabHost.setup();        
    return sTabHost;
}

 public addTabItem(final String url, String tabTitle, Drawable tabIcon)
 {
  TabSpec ts1 = sTabHost.newTabSpec(tabTitle); 
        if(tabIcon==null)
            ts1.setIndicator(tabTitle);
        else
            ts1.setIndicator(tabTitle,tabIcon);        
        ts1.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory(){
             @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            public View createTabContent(String tag)
             {               
                //Creating webview inside a layout   
             }  
        }); 
        sTabHost.addTab(ts1); //Here throws NullPointer exception.
        sTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
 }
```

How can I achieve my requirement.?

Answer (score 0):

Are you not using an XML layout? It's much more efficient and tidy than what you have above...

You haven't included any logcat so there isnt much to go on but it seems to me that the issue is your addTabItem tries to make something arbitrary and use it as the content when really you want to be using the frameLayout as the content so try passing that into the method and setting it as the content